# chef provisiong by using Vagarnt

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am new to CHEF provisioning. These are steps, I am following to spin-up VMs on Vagrant.

```
Step 1: Cloned the Git code (https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning.git)
Step 2: gem install chef-provisioning chef-provisioning-vagrant
Step 3: export CHEF_DRIVER=vagrant

Step 4: export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER=virtualbox
Step 5: chef-client -z vagrant_linux.rb simple.rb
```

I am not able to figure out the error.

> Error executing action `converge` on resource 'machine[Makeitpossible]'
>
> STDERR:The HGFS kernel module was not found on the running virtual machine.
>   This must be installed for shared folders to work properly. Please
>   install the VMware tools within the guest and try again. Note that
>   the VMware tools installation will succeed even if HGFS fails
>   to properly install. Carefully read the output of the VMware tools
>   installation to verify the HGFS kernel modules were installed properly.

vagrant_linux.rb:

```
 require 'chef/provisioning/vagrant_driver'

 vagrant_box 'sles11sp3.box' do
        url 'https://jenkins-hzn.eng.vmware.com/tools/vagrant/sles11sp3.box'
 end

 with_driver 'vagrant'

 with_machine_options :vagrant_options => {
     'vm.box' => 'sles11sp3.box'
 }
```

Simple.rb

```
 require 'chef/provisioning'

 machine 'Makeitpossible' do
    tag 'itsa_me'
    converge true
 end
```

Comment: Could you show your vagrant_linux.rb and simple.rb files content ? (Having provider virtualbox and error messages about vmware sounds strange)

Comment: require 'chef/provisioning/vagrant_driver'

vagrant_box 'sles11sp3.box' do
  url 'https://jenkins-hzn.eng.vmware.com/tools/vagrant/sles11sp3.box'
end

with_driver 'vagrant'

with_machine_options :vagrant_options => {
  'vm.box' => 'sles11sp3.box'
}require 'chef/provisioning'

machine 'Makeitpossible' do
  tag 'itsa_me'
  converge true
end
~

Comment: Edit your question, comments are bad to format code.

Comment: Did I edit properly to get something which makes sense or did I misunderstood something in your code ?

Comment: It is proper now... Thanks so much.

Comment: Ok, that's the raw exemples with a different box, not really working with virtualbox, so I can't be of help here.

Comment: Cool but can you please give your vagrant_linux.rb and simple.rb? I will try to run.

Comment: Unless you share my vsphere Env and source image, my files won't be of use. The problem seems to be in your base image, I'm.not using suse on virtualbox I can NOT help more, sorry.

Comment: If you have any good notes or tutorial on CHEF provision please, do share. we are trying to spin-up VMs to VSphere and I am struggling to configure the files and there are a lot of errors.

Comment: Your error is due to the box you're using, nothing related to chef, start with basic one like Ubuntu precise to ramp up learning before trying to use exotic boxes...